# Storing the cluster robust standard error to create a new variable— Stata 12 for Mac

Tags: stata, standard-error

I need to store the value for the cluster robust standard error in order to use it to create a new variable.

I am able to get the cluster robust standard error with the mean command, but stata does not store this value.

Do you have any suggestions about how to calculate the cluster robust standard error for an estimate and then store this value in order to use it to create a new variable?

Comment: are you sure you are not confusing the standard deviation (which is a square root of the variance, and is a property of its marginal distribution irrespective of the sample design) and the standard error (the estimate of the sampling variability of an estimator, which may or may not be a good estimate, and depends on all the distributions involved, as well as the sample design)?

Comment: you're right, i want standard errors. as i was writing the above question, i realized it doesn't make sense to use the summarize command. I'll delete that part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might almost do the trick. There might be a more elegant way to do this. Toy data, nonsensical example:

```
/* Get some data */
webuse nhanes2f, clear
svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)

/* get the standard error of the constant, which is the mean */
svy: reg zinc
display _se[_cons]
generate se = _se[_cons]

/* Verify that this is correct */
svy: mean zinc
```

However, you also want to cluster, which complicates things. I think if you only have survey weights (aka first stage clusters), you can do:

```
reg zinc [pweight=finalwgt], cluster(region)
```

There might a way to do what you want with -glamm-, which is user-written command. You should ask this question on Statalist if you don't get much of response here.

Comment: `psuid` IS the cluster variable in your `svyset`. If you cluster by region on top of that, then frankly I don't know what you are doing... even though the example is intended to be non-sensical :). Other than that, technically everytyhing is fine, no need for `gllamm`.